# Azure site to site proposals with Strongswan IPSec

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, encryption, azure

I'm here trying to connect a Linux Ubuntu VPC Machine to Azure Cloud network interface, only thing I can't suss out is how to config my IKE and ESP at my end to match the Below -

IKEv2 Encryption | GCMAES256, AES256 IKEv2 Integrity | GCMAES256, SHA384, SHA256, SHA1 DH Group | DHGroup2 IPsec Encryption | GCMAES256, AES256 IPsec Integrity | GCMAES256, SHA256 PFS Group | None, PFS24, ECP384, ECP256, PFS2048, PFS2, PFS1

Every variation I've tried so far

```
#ike=chacha20poly1305-sha512-curve25519-prfsha512,aes256gcm16-sha384-prfsha384-ecp384,aes256-sha1-modp1024,aes128-sha1-modp1024,3des-sha1-modp1024! 
#ike=3des-sha1-modp1024! 
ike=aes256-sha256-modp1024,aes256-sha1-modp1024! 
#esp=chacha20poly1305-sha512,aes256gcm16-ecp384,aes256-sha256,aes256-sha1,3des-sha1! 
#esp=aes256-sha256-modp1024! 
esp=aes256-sha256-modp1024!
```

I've tried to follow and decipher things from -> https://docs.strongswan.org/docs/5.9/config/IKEv2CipherSuites.html but I can't figure out which ones to use

Answer (score 0):

Following configuration

```
ike=aes256-sha1-modp1024!
esp=aes256-sha1-modp2048!
```

worked for me with Azure default IPsec / IKE policy.

Azure-side default IPSSec/IKO parameters are documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpn-devices#ipsec. triplet on strongswan-side must match with defaults unless OP has configured own IPSec/IKE policy.

One way to solve the issue is just to configure same config on both sides.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-ipsecikepolicy-rm-powershell#part-2---supported-cryptographic-algorithms--key-strengths) links to RFCs but IANA site has better mapping for from DHGroups to keywords: https://docs.strongswan.org/docs/5.9/config/IKEv2CipherSuites.html#_diffie_hellman_groups

- The current esp configuration OP has does not match with default configs.
- The fifth line should work if Azure Gateway is responder
- The fourth line should work if Azure Gateway is initiator

Next steps:

1. Try suggested configuration
2. Post config from Azure-side: IPSec/IKE policy, VPN type: routed or policy-based
3. doublecheck traffic selector if applicable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-ipsecikepolicy-rm-powershell#part-2---supported-cryptographic-algorithms--key-strengths
4. error messages from logs

Comment: Could you elaborate on this a little more?